# Is it possible to insert a category list view inside an article?

Tags: joomla-3.x, category, view

I want to get a category list view inside an article (in this case, inside a tab in an article), but I want to see this category list view styled like when a menu item type shows a category list: a table with header, hits, date, number of articles to show, pagination, etc...
What I obtain is only a list with the articles titles, date and hits, all together in the same line, but not in a table layout.

Is it possible get the table layout in any way and insert it in an article (inside a tab, for example)??

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you use php in this article? You could do a query and then list how you want with foreach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use the `Articles - Category` module that's shipped with Joomla.

1. Create module
2. Set all the options you require
3. Assign it to a custom position, e.g `category-test`
4. In your article, add the following code snippet `{loadposition category-test}`

By default, this module uses a list layout, so if you'd like to display the data in a table, you can easily perform a [Template Override](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core).